# Storing array[i] from forloop to a new array returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am currently working on a matching algorithm that would match an array of strings against another array of string.If it match completely (===) it will store the results into unSafeResult array.If it matches through Regex , it will store the results inside warningResult array.However when i console.log(warningResult).It shows

```
warning (2) [undefined × 1, "SUGAR.↵CHOCOLATE LIQUOR"]
main.js:41867 warning (3) [undefined × 2, "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL"]
main.js:41867 warning (6) [undefined × 5, "RAPESEED OIL"]
main.js:41867 warning (7) [undefined × 6, "PALM OIL"]
main.js:41867 warning (8) [undefined × 7, "SUNFLOWER OIL"]
main.js:41867 warning (11) [undefined × 10, "RAPESEED OIL"]
main.js:41867 warning (12) [undefined × 11, "PALM OIL"]
```

And then if try to pass the array to another page it only returns 1 element only which is

```
[undefined × 11, "PALM OIL"]
```

Is there any way that i can solve this bug? The expected output should be all of them should be under one array

```
"HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL"
"RAPESEED OIL"
"PALM OIL"
"SUNFLOWER OIL"
"RAPESEED OIL"
"PALM OIL"
```

below is the codes

```
matchText(array){        
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        var label = this.labels[i];

        var ingredients = label.description.toString().split(/[(,)]/igm).map(function (ingredients){return ingredients.trim()}, {});

        let ingredientList:string[] = ingredients;
        let ingredientUpdatedList:string[];

        for(var k = 0; k<ingredientList.length; k++){
        if(ingredientList[k] === ""){
            ingredientList = ingredientList.filter((ingredientList) =>{
                return ingredientList.trim() != '';
            });
        }
    }


    for(var j = 0; j<ingredientList.length; j++){

        let allergy:string[] = ["OIL","SUGAR"];

        var unSafeResult = [];

        for(var e = 0; e<allergy.length; e++) {
            var regexp = new RegExp(allergy[e], "igm");

            if(ingredientList[j] == allergy[e]){

                unSafeResult[j] = ingredientList[j];   
                console.log('unSafe',unSafeResult);
            }

            if(ingredientList[j].match(regexp)){
                this.counter++;

                var warningResult = [];

                warningResult[j] = ingredientList[j].valueOf(); //here is the issue

                console.log('warning', warningResult);

                //console.log('Match');
                //console.log('Ingredients that matched',unSafeResult);
            }
            else {
                //console.log('No Match');

            }
        }

    }

    if(this.counter >0){
        this.navCtrl.push(UnSafePage,{unSafeResult,warningResult});
    }
    else{
        this.navCtrl.push(SafePage);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason about `undefined`:**

When you define an empty array, and set something to the `array` by index **large than 0**, it will be filled with **`undefined` automatically** until the index you used.

Example to confirm:

```js
var testArr = [];

testArr[5] = 'test';

console.log(testArr);
```

**Solution:**

You should define `warningResult` out of `for-loop`, and push items to it according to your other conditions.

```js
var ingredientList = ["HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL",
  "RAPESEED OIL",
  "PALM OIL",
  "SUNFLOWER OIL",
  "RAPESEED OIL",
  "PALM OIL"
];

var warningResult = [];

for (var j = 0; j < ingredientList.length; j++) {
  // only aviable in for loop
  //var warningResult = [];
  //warningResult[j] = ingredientList[j].valueOf();

  warningResult.push(ingredientList[j].valueOf());

}

console.log('warning', warningResult);
```

Comment: Hello , thank you for the help and the answer. It is clear and concise , the code now works like a charm!

Comment: @GX-X glad to help :)

Comment: When using a `for` loop, it is good practice to either use a block scoped form (`for (let i = 0;...`) or declare the loop variable at the top level. `var` is function scoped not block scoped.